# perfect-scrollbar default scrollbar remains and the "perfect-scrollbar" not functional

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe, perfect-scrollbar

I really need help with this one. I would like to replace the default scrollbar on my iframe with the "perfect scrollbar".
I have downloaded the perfect scrollbar. I also have included the needed files into my html document. According to the documentation, I set up the style of content container inside my iframe. The result is, that when I load my main page and move the mouse cursor on iframe, the "perfect-scrollbar" appears, but the default scrollbar remains. Next issue is, that the new scrollbar is not functional at all. It starts on the top of the iframe content and it ends at the bottom of the iframe content so I can not scroll with it.

HTML of my iframe content page:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="sk" lang="sk">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/iframestyle.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/perfect-scrollbar-0.4.8.min.css" />
    <!-- latest jQuery direct from google's CDN -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/perfect-scrollbar-0.4.8.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/perfect-scrollbar-0.4.8.with-mousewheel.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scroll.js"></script>
    <title>TITLE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="amfCont">
      ..... // content to be scrolled
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#amfCont {
  font-family:"Verdana";
  text-align:justify;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

JS (included scroll.js)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
"use strict";
  $('#amfCont').perfectScrollbar();
});
```

Can anyone point out what do I have wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Try [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) in your iframe.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQuery Scrollbar Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.css">

        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/jquery.scrollbar.js"></script>

        <script>
            jQuery(function($){
                $('.page-wrapper').scrollbar();
            });
        </script>

        <style type="text/css">
            html, body, .page-wrapper {
                border: none;
                height: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                width: 100%;
            }

            .page-content {
                padding: 10px 20px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page-wrapper scrollbar-macosx">
            <div class="page-content">
                [CONTENT HERE]
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In example above I've used `scrollbar-macosx` class, but you can choose any from predefined styles or make your own custom scrollbar - it's fully CSS customizable.

Comment: Thank you. I have noticed that in IE there is the default scroll and also the new scroll bar. How can I avoid showing the default one? I have used it just like in your example. Thank you

Comment: I've checked in IE7, IE8, IE9. If you open this page in browser (not as iframe), IE7 **ALWAYS** shows standard page scrollbar, even if content is smaller - there is nothing to do with this behavior. Other IE are good. But if you open this page as IFRAME, standard scrollbar won't be displayed.

Comment: Ok, I am using IE 11. I am opening the page with my content like a iframe on my main page, and there are both (the standard scroll and the new jQuery) at the same time. Why is that happening, when it should display only the jQuery, according to what you said?

Comment: I've checked in IE10 && IE11 (Win7 SP1), everything works well. Can you provide screenshot & html of the page you use?

Answer (score 0):

`#amfCont` needs a `height` property for this plugin to work. Here's the example from the docs.

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%; /* Or whatever you want (eg. 400px) */
}
```