# Customize scrollbar that update window.scrollY?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I added customize scrollbar in my site that doesn't update window.scrollY and my picture does'nt fade in.
my code is this:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' href='Style/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='Js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function ($) {
                    $(window).load(function () {
                        $("body").mCustomScrollbar();
                    });


    })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Is any customize jquery scroll bar for 1.9.1 version that update window.scrollY??
thank u for help.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because custom scrollbar emulates scroll using content offset, not scrollTop/scrollLeft. You can try [jQuery Scrollbar](http://github.com/gromo/jquery.scrollbar) that scrolls page, but you will have to make page wrapper, apply scrollbar to it and listen scroll events on this container, not on window!

Example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403144/perfect-scrollbar-default-scrollbar-remains-and-the-perfect-scrollbar-not-func/22407638). Also, you can't remove native page scrollbar in IE7