# Custom scrollbar using jquery for iframe with customer url

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe, scrollbar

I have a client who wants me to add a custom scrollbar to an iframe. In the iframe I'm bringing in the clients retail website, so the page height does not stay the same all the time.

On this site click on the "Retail Opportunities" link and a modal opens with their retail career site. I have tried adding a custom scroll bar but I had issues when I click on the jobs navigation since that page gets long. Had to take it off since it would not scroll beyond the initial height of the home page.

http://careers-adidas-group-com.tmpqa.com/

Does anyone know of any jquery that will work no matter what the height is. I'm still looking in the meantime.

Thanks
Debbie

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of cool jQuery scrollbar plugins:

- [jQuery Scrollbar](http://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/)
- [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)
- [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)
- [perfect-scrollbar](http://noraesae.github.com/perfect-scrollbar/)
- [slimScroll](http://rocha.la/jQuery-slimScroll/)
- [Scroller](http://formstone.it/scroller/)
- [jQuery Custom Scrollbar](https://github.com/mzubala/jquery-custom-scrollbar)
- [baron](https://github.com/Diokuz/baron/)
- [NiceScroll](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/)

Some better, some worse, some can offer additional functionality you may need. I recommend the first one, but it's all up to you (you can compare scrollbars functionality in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ao4HbHsCLP0YdEhnZVh1WGZSbXloekZiNWlaNElnTnc&usp=sharing)). To use custom scrollbar in iFrame you should be able to modify iFrame page content to include styles, scripts and make necessary changes in HTML structure. Here is [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403144/perfect-scrollbar-default-scrollbar-remains-and-the-perfect-scrollbar-not-func/22407638#22407638) how to use jQuery Scrollbar in iFrame.

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see if this solves my problem. Right now this project is on hold. Once I work on this I will let you know which one works.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery lib I've always used has been Perfect Scrollbar. Its well documented, widely used and is easy to setup.

Demo & Download: [Click Here](http://noraesae.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/)

Hopefully this is what you need

Comment: Thanks I will try this and see if this solves my problem. Right now this project is on hold.